# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable (generator error)

Tags: python, generator

I'm not seeing how can I get rid of the error. Is this happening because of the use of `while`? I want to print the first 12 non-prime numbers.

```
from math import sqrt
from itertools import count, islice

def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False

    for number in islice(count(2), int(sqrt(n) - 1)):
        if n % number == 0:
            return False

    return True


def positive_integers_generator():
    n = 1
    while True:
        x = yield n
        if x is not None:
            n = x
        else:
            n += 1

k = 12
g = positive_integers_generator()

count = 0 
while count < k:
  value = next(g)
  if not is_prime(value):
     count += 1
     print(value)
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace for this error? indicating which line it happened on?

Comment: your problem is `count(2)` in this line `for number in islice(count(2), int(sqrt(n) - 1)):`

Comment: `positive_integers_generator` looks far too complicated; when do you ever send a value *into* the generator to be assigned to `x`? `n=1; while True; do yield n; n += 1` seems sufficient. In any event, `g = itertools.count(1)` would be far simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have replaced the `count` function you imported with an integer, sicne you are starting your main with `count = 0`. Next time you try to call it as a function, you get this error.